# $cordovaImagePicker working on Android emulator, but not IOS phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

So I built my app on an Android emulator, and everything works fine (users can select images). Then I build for IOS (the actual phone) and everything works fine except the image selection. I did an alert between ionic ready (and the callback) and both popup. Then I do an alert(JSON.parse($cordovaImagePicker)) and a blank JSON object shows up ( "{}" ) any ideas?

Comment: Please check console in XCODE when you run the build for iOS. There might be some useful error details which can help

Comment: @AlexRyltsov I don't have a mac to do such. I build in the cloud using Ionic's cloud builder. Any other ideas?